# How do you save multiple lists into a csv file with a title for each list?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have multiple matrices (let' say there are 30 of them) that need to be stored into a single csv file. Since there are so many of them, I want each matrix to have number before them. For example, `0` or `Matrix-0` for matrix 0, `1` for matrix 1, and so on.

I have written the following code. Both `temp1` and `temp2` are matrices (list), which I append to a dataframe. But I have a problem storing them all without mixing all the matrices together (they are all different matrices but of the same size). I need to tell which matrix comes from which iteration, etc.

```
def my_function(df):
..............................
..............................
    conf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred_class)
    print(conf_matrix)
    df_conf_matrix = pd.DataFrame(conf_matrix)

    return(df_conf_matrix)

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0,30):
    print("**ITERATION-%d**"%i)
    temp1, temp2 = my_function(my_df)
    df1 = df1.append(temp1)
    df2 = df2.append(temp2)

df1.to_csv('file_name1')
df2.to_csv('file_name2')
```

Comment: You are not giving much to work with, please identify what `my_function` does, and a sample of the input and output.

Comment: It's a quite long function. But basically all it did is doing some classification and return the confusion matrix of said classification. Will add that. - Added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a index column that tells what iteration the row came from. You can then sort by that column. I assume that your function returns 2 dataframes.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0,30):
    print("**ITERATION-%d**"%i)
    temp1, temp2 = my_function(df1)
    temp1['iteration'] = 'iteration-{}'.format(i)
    temp2['iteration'] = 'iteration-{}'.format(i)
    df1 = df1.append(temp1)
    df2 = df2.append(temp2)

df1.to_csv('file_name1.csv')
df2.to_csv('file_name2.csv')
```